# 100% height for DIV using jquery - how to make it relate to parent

Tags: jquery, height

I'm using this jquery script for extending a child DIV 100%.  It works fine, but the DIV is extending beyond the browser window so I must scroll down always.  Is it possible to change the 100% height to be related to a parent DIV rathe than the document?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stretch").animate({ height: $(document).height() }, 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is:

For direct parent:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $stretch = $("#stretch");

    $stretch.animate({ height: $stretch.parent().height() }, 500 );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RRqr4/

If it's not the direct parent, you can substitute `closest` for `parent`.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on "no bueno"?  This does work in general  http://jsfiddle.net/RRqr4/  if it does not work for you there is something else going on.

Comment: My parents are:  #body_wrap    {width:100%;min-height: 100%;height: auto !important;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto -145px;}
#frame_body    {width:771px;margin: 0 auto;}

Comment: I updated it with my code and I can;t figure out the bug:  http://jsfiddle.net/RRqr4/1/

Comment: Your elements have no height so the parent height is 0.  http://jsfiddle.net/RRqr4/3/

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I'm using a sticky footer so I wanted the footer to always move up with the window.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $stretch = $("#stretch");
    $('#stretch').animate({ height: $stretch.parent().height() }, 500 );
});
```

or if its not the imeditate parent:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $stretch = $("#stretch");
    $('#stretch').animate({ height: $stretch.closest('parent-selector').height() }, 500 );
});
```

Comment: Lost the DIV - does not appear.

Comment: This actually won't work because `this` in this context is not the element.

Comment: find a pastebin site and paste the html please

Comment: the problem is that you haven't set a height on the parent! do #frame_body {width:771px;margin: 0 auto; height:500px;} and then try